# ConnectionString для БД MSSQL в WinForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Скажите какое значение давать  `"Data source=` что бы подключалась к северу и экземпляру сервера не смотря что давали при установлении севера?
Это код строки соединения в файле App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConectionString"  connectionString="Data source=localhost;initial catalog=BandivanKat; trusted_connection=true;Integrated Security=False"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если база данных находится, например, у провайдера на хостинге, то в настройках хостинга будет указана connection string, например, такая

```
Data Source=u2345.mssql.somehost.eu;Initial Catalog=u12345;User ID=u12345
```

Ее надо просто скопировать в MyConectionString в connectionString.

Comment: это же не веб приложения а настольная WinForms?или же я не знаю кто тут провайдер кто хостинг не  объясните если такое есть для настольного приложения?

Comment: а sql server установлен на том компьютере, где это приложение запускается?

Comment: да установлен,но не может подключатся к базе

Comment: посмотрите настройки в SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: и что искать там?

Comment: имя сервера, точно не помню где. имя может быть например, таким "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -- его надо указать вместо localhost после "Data source="

Comment: посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)